# Why my multisite is this slow? (stats inside)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, ssl, apache

I'm building a network for my business and I faced interesting issues during testing the network.

FYI, I'm using very light self-made theme on my network sites and only one plugin.

For testing purpose, I made **exactly the same** site under main site (subdomain) and in the mapped domain. Actually, the faster site (subdomain) has more content to download than slower one.

Image of the faster site page load - when its loaded the very first file:

[image]

Image of the slowe site page load:

[image]

That's not big deal, I can deal with that. But what makes me wonder are the next stats.

Faster site:

[image]

Slower site:
[image]

Basically, what the sites are doing here is that JS code fetches some data from server-side, that's all.

My server's stats:

1 GB - memory

1 vCPU

25 GB - SSD disk

I'll upgrade my server to 2GB when I'm starting to get real clients. After hours of testing, I'm pretty positive that this is not caused by incorrect DNS settings.

I'm using SSL, but the redirect settings are also identical between subdomain site and mapped domain.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Additional things to check:

1. Email usage – if using cPanel, you can check this via Disk Usage;
2. Cron-jobs – you can see these in cPanel. However, you can also search in phpMyAdmin for DB cron-jobs;
3. Check traffic spikes/time-of-day in Google Analytics.